# как сделать сплит сообщения всех аргументов после определенного?

Tags: python, telebot

Пользователь пишет `ник test`, `test` берется как первый аргумент и указывается как имя пользователя, но если пользователь напишет `ник test test`, то возьмется только первый аргумент, что и правильно, но как сделать, чтобы бот если что мог обработать больше аргументов? Функция недоработана, имя выводится в `print(nickname)`

```py
elif message.text.startswith('ник'):
    nickname_change(message)

def nickname_change(message):
    nickname = ''
    args_nickname = message.text.split()[1]
    if args_nickname:
        try:
            nickname = str(args_nickname)
        except ValueError:
            bot.reply_to(message, text='Ошибка')
            return

    print(nickname)
```

Comment: `args_nickname = message.text.split()[1:]`, ну или `args_nickname = " ".join(message.text.split()[1:])`

Comment: @ZxNuClear Вы можете написать это в ответ?

Comment: `_, *args_nickname = message.text.split()` или   `_, args_nickname = txt.split(' ',1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте срез, чтобы получить список из текста после ника:

```
args_nickname = message.text.split()[1:]
```

либо сразу получите из него готовую строку:

```
args_nickname = " ".join(message.text.split()[1:])
```